# How to create a custom asp.Net Templated Databound Control?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, templates, controls

I would like to know if there is a good source of documentation for creating Asp.Net Templated Databound Controls or code samples for simple controls.

All the documentation I have seen on the net seems way too complex. Is there a place where it is explained in a simple and easy to understand manner ?

I could also be interested in text books, if this is the place where you have found the simplest explanation on how to do it.

Note: I don't care if articles/code samples are for C# or VB.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Developing Microsoft ASP.NET Server Controls and Components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615829)
- http://www.nikhilk.net/

Those are all you need to know, in addition to the MSDN documentation: [Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx).

It's not a simple area.

Comment: +1 the book is the bible of custom controls. but there is only one chapter about databound controls.

Comment: True. The book needs to be updated to .NET 2.0. Maybe even to .NET 3.5 SP1. But it's the best there is.

Comment: +1 for the book ref, I checked it a bit, but will check it more in depth later, and if it suits my needs, will give you the answer